# Error Installing VS.net 2003 on a Windows 2012 R2 Server

Tags: visual-studio, .net-1.1

For various reasons, I have to install VS.Net 2003 on a 2012 R2 Server. 
I was able to install the VS 2003 Pre-reqs when I tried to install the VS.net 2003 server itself, I am getting the following error:

> Error 1309: Error reading from File D:............\adodb.dll.
>   Verify that the file exists and you have access to it.

I am able to see the file. I run the setup exe as administrator.Still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple CD-DVD ROM drives, you should turn off the extra drives and try again.

If you don't have  a multiple CD-ROM system, try to copy the CD-DVD's contents to the Hard Disk Drive and run the installation from there.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to download the file from internet and repleace the one from the folder, but first back up the old one

1. Download the file adodb.dll to your desktop.
2. Move the dll file to the program directory missing the file.
3. If step 2 doesn't work. Move adodb.dll to the system directory.

   - Windows XP,Vista, and Windows 7 - `C:\Windows\System32`
     on 2012 R2 Server should be the same directory file

Answer (score 0):

It seems under Win2K12 R2, the Installer of MSVS.Net 2003 does not pick up the short forms of the paths to the installation files... I even suspect that server doesn't support 8.3 forms of the paths.

For the case the 8.3 support is there, try to run the installer in Compatibility Mode (right-click on the setup executable and choose Properties, then tab "Compatibility", then either run the Compatibility Troubleshooter oder select the Checkbox "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" and choose from the dropdown Windows 7 oder Windows XP (SP 3)).